# base64_encode - different results locally than on host after host server upgrade

Tags: php, base64

I have a database with image data stored. To display this I use:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode(thePhotoData) ."'/>";
```

This has always worked until a couple of days ago when my host upgraded their server.

Images display correctly locally but when I compare the results from the base64 results they are different as shown in the image below.

What might have changed due to the updgrade to cause this? I have tested the raw data from the host by exporting to local and can view the images so the data has not been corrupted.

Local:
php 7.1.27,  MySQL 10.1.38-MariaDB, Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Host
php 7.3.28,  MySQL 8.0.25-MySQL Community Server, Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

[image]

Comment: first step would be to decode the base64 to see the actual raw data. First guess would be that the images being generated aren't the same with your host likely generating a bad image or maybe even an error message  (because your example shows a broken image). You don't show code for you thePhotoData is created...

Comment: Thanks - the raw jpeg code is sent from an iPad (camera pic). Everything was working fine until their upgrade.

Comment: My point was that you're focusing too much on base64 encode breaking. Something else (like how the jpg is being received/processed) could have broken during the upgrade. Try decoding that broken base64 manually to see what's there....

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get access to the old server, downloaded all the images and now store them as seperate image files rather than the data in the database. I have been meaning to do this for some time but the upgrade forced me to get it done.